# How to access Java std Library Source Code when Android Sources Plugin is installed?

Tags: android-source

Have installed [Android Sources Eclipse Plugin](http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/), and wonder how can I access the source code to Java standard library classes, e.g., `java.lang.String`? 
Indeed, I could extend the *sources.zip*-file (installed by the [plugin](http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/)) with the missing source files, like the *java.** packages source files, but is there any other more seamless way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The sources of java library are situated in the project libcore. The full path `libcore/luni/src/main/java` There you can find `java.lang` package where String class is defined.
So you have two possibilities to look into resources:

1. Download the sources of AOSP
2. Browse sources in the Internet.